# IFS and bash code to read enter pressed by the user

Tags: bash

Is there something wrong with this code

```
IFS=''
for i in `seq 1 20`; do
        sleep 1
        echo $((20-$i)) seconds till abort ... 
done

variable="dummy"
read -p "Enter to continue" -t 1 -N 1 variable
echo -e "\n"
while [ "$variable" != $'\x0a' ] 
do
read -p "Enter to continue" -t 1 -N 1 variable
echo -e "\n" 
done
```

The error is 20: syntax error in expression (error token is "2

If I remove the IFS='' then the countdown works fine, but then the part with "enter to continue" fails.

Is it advisable to put IFS='', coz I have seen that this variable is a delimiter for word boundaries?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can just do: `for i in {20..1}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done`

Comment: But you don't need it toggled to `''` for this block of code (at least that I can tell), so why set it here?

Comment: @JNevill added the block of code, where it is required. maybe you have another solution for this block of code, so taht I can do away with IFS.

Comment: Not sure on doing away with IFS, but for sure you can move that `IFS=''` line down to just above the line of code where you need it. You may want to store the existing IFS into a variable so that you can restore your IFS when you are finished setting it to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

By setting IFS to the empty string you are only entering the loop once, and in the iteration of the loop the variable i is a 20 line string.  `$(())` doesn't know what to do with that string, so it tells you about the syntax error. (Note that the error token is 19 lines long, but you only paid attention to the first line.)

If you really need to manipulate IFS for other portions of your script (you probably don't!), you can do:

```
unset IFS
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
        IFS=''
        sleep 1
        echo $((20-$i)) seconds till abort ... 
done
```

Comment: awesome.. can you please tell me how can I code the other part of my script without setting IFS. If I remove the IFS part then while [ "$variable" != $'\x0a' ]  doesnt work anymore

Comment: If you leave IFS alone, you can check the value returned by read.  If it timed out, read will return non-zero (eg, it will fail).  If the user entered 'return', read will return 0.